# Can I ask a question that is supplementary to another's users question?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have found this question about potential energy  [What is potential energy truly?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103377/what-is-potential-energy-truly). I can not make comments.

Can I ask a question supplementary to this question?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, if you have a follow-up question you can ask it as a separate question. Make sure to be very clear about why the question you ask is different from the original question. It's probably a good idea to link to the original question to help provide context.

Comment: Thank you. I' ll post my question a soon as i find time.